# Best way to store "Other" data into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database-schema

I have a form with radio buttons which stores the value (which is the ID) in my MySQL database along with the necessary information from the user.

```
INSERT INTO table (user_id, name, address, prefer_id) VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?);
```

So when I try to fetch the data, I use `LEFT JOIN`, to get the necessary description from `table2`:

```
SELECT a.name, a.address, b.prefer_desc FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.prefer_id = b.prefer_id
WHERE a.user_id = ?
```

But I have created an other option, in case the option the user prefers is not in the list. A textbox will appear when the user selects `Other` in the list of radio buttons so they can type-in freely their preferred data. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/m4c3k8tc/) to see an example.

The first logic that I've thinked of is to create a separate table which stores the typed-in data of the user.

other_tb:

```
 other_id | user_id | typed_in |
----------+---------+----------+
    1     |     1   |   cake   |
    2     |     3   |   pizza  |
```

So when I fetch the data, I use `php`'s `if()` condition if the `prefer_id` is `4` (or other), and if it does, I will use another `SELECT` query to get the other data in `other_tb` table.

```
SELECT typed_in FROM other_tb WHERE user_id = ?
```

Is there a way to do all of this in a single query?

OR

Is this the best option, or is there a right or better way in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
    a.name, 
    a.address, 
    IF(a.prefer_id=4,(SELECT typed_in FROM other_tb WHERE user_id = a.user_id),b.prefer_desc) as prefer_desc
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table2 b 
    ON a.prefer_id = b.prefer_id
WHERE a.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the second table as you described, and you want to keep the same format of the output and assuming the records in `other_tb` are unique for each `user_id`, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT a.name, a.address, 
       CASE 
           WHERE a.prefer_id = 4 THEN c.typed_in
           ELSE b.prefer_desc
       END CASE AS prefer_desc
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table2   b ON a.prefer_id = b.prefer_id
LEFT JOIN other_tb c ON a.user_id   = c.user_id
WHERE a.user_id = ?
```

I think this can also be written as:

```
SELECT a.name, a.address, 
       CASE a.prefer_id
           WHERE 4 THEN c.typed_in
           ELSE b.prefer_desc
       END CASE AS prefer_desc
FROM table a
LEFT JOIN table2   b ON a.prefer_id = b.prefer_id
LEFT JOIN other_tb c ON a.user_id   = c.user_id
WHERE a.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that I was able to practice depending on the situation:

1. Allow users to add more options so that their answer is still indexed to `table2`. So when fetching data, you may still use `LEFT JOIN` to get the user's preferred option without any other condition. But this method will allow users to see the options that was added by other users.
2. If the options are "fixed" and only the administrator is allowed to add options to `table2`, have another column to `table1`, which stores the `other` answer of the user (let say `other_option` column). This method allows the user to still freely state their option without adding options to `table2`.

Here is `table1`:

```
+---------+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
| user_id | name | address | prefer_id | other_option |
+---------+------+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

What I do is I put 0 to `prefer_id` if the user prefers to answer `other_option`. So your program expects that if the `prefer_id` is 0, you have an input in `other_option`.